Prevent add_custom_command from running when packaging
I have some cmake which copies SFML dlls into the proper binary location when building
add_executable(my_target
    main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(my_target
    PRIVATE
        sfml-graphics
        sfml-audio
        sfml-system
        sfml-window
)

set_target_properties(my_target PROPERTIES
  OUTPUT_NAME MyTarget
  RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin
)

if(WIN32)
    add_custom_command(
        TARGET my_target
        COMMENT "Copy OpenAL DLL"
        PRE_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${SFML_SOURCE_DIR}/extlibs/bin/$<IF:$<EQUAL:${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P},8>,x64,x86>/openal32.dll $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:my_target>
        VERBATIM
    )
    if(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
        add_custom_command(
            TARGET my_target
            COMMENT "Copy SFML DLLs"
            POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:my_target> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:my_target>
            COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
        )
    endif()
endif()

When I package up the project with cpack, that custom command also runs to copy the SFML DLLs and OpenAL DLL. However, I already have packaging logic for those:
include(GNUInstallDirs) 

set(OS_NAME "Unknown")
if(WIN32)
    set(OS_NAME "Windows")
    set(CPACK_GENERATOR "ZIP;NSIS")
    install(TARGETS my_target RUNTIME DESTINATION .)

    # Copy SFML DLLs and OpenAL DLL during installation
    install(FILES ${SFML_SOURCE_DIR}/extlibs/bin/$<IF:$<EQUAL:${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P},8>,x64,x86>/openal32.dll DESTINATION .)
    if(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
        install(FILES $<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:my_target> DESTINATION .)
    endif()
elseif(APPLE)
    set(OS_NAME "MacOS")
    set(CPACK_GENERATOR "ZIP;DragNDrop")

    #Set the properties for the macOS application bundle
    set_target_properties(my_target PROPERTIES
        MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    )
    
    install(TARGETS my_target 
        BUNDLE DESTINATION . COMPONENT Runtime
    )
    
    # Set the CPack properties
    set(CPACK_BUNDLE_NAME "My Target")
elseif(UNIX)
    set(OS_NAME "Linux")
    set(CPACK_GENERATOR "ZIP")
    install(TARGETS my_target RUNTIME DESTINATION .)
endif()

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${PROJECT_NAME}-${PROJECT_VERSION}-${OS_NAME}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/README.md")
set(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/LICENSE")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH}")


include(CPack)

This generates an install package on windows which has
bin/
include/
lib/
openal32.dll*   
MyTarget.exe*    
sfml-audio-d-2.dll*   
sfml-graphics-d-2.dll*
sfml-system-d-2.dll*  
sfml-window-d-2.dll*  
share/
Uninstall.exe*  

share, include, and lib are all included because SFML is included with fetch content and I can't turn off those installations. However, bin seems to be included because of the add_custom_command that copies DLLs to the runtime destination for my target.
How do I prevent add_custom_command from running when I package my app?
